# Is it possible to have an Objective-C Category that is only loaded if the method doesn't already exist?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-category

On a past project (pre-iOS 4.0), I wrote the following category method on `NSSortDescriptor`:

```
+ (id)sortDescriptorWithKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending;
```

When Apple released the iOS SDK 4.0, it included the exact same method (which presumably does exactly the same thing). Is it possible to write a category that is only added to the runtime either if you're running a particular OS version, or probably more to the point, if there isn't already a method declared with the same signature?

In this case, it's probably safe to override the `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:` method with a category, which will give both iOS 3 and iOS 4 support, since my version will almost certainly do the same thing. I'd still prefer not to mess with system defined methods if possible, due to the (unlikely) possibility of breaking things in edge cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, no.

The way I'd recommend doing this would be to have a `my_sortDescriptorWithKey:` which can then check if the class responds to `sortDescriptorWithKey:` and uses that if it does, otherwise use your own implementation.

Comment: I'm not saying it's necessarily a good idea for production code, but would it be possible to do it by using `runtime.h` functions? Say to use `class_addMethod` after checking to see if such a method already exists by using something like `class_getClassMethod`?

Comment: Yes, as Jeff showed that is also possible, but I try to avoid runtime hacks when possible.

Answer (score 5):

Joshua’s answer will work well, but if you want to get *really* fancy, you can use the dynamic nature of Objective-C to modify the `NSSortDescriptor` class to your liking:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

SEL theSelector = @selector(sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:);

if ( ! [NSSortDescriptor instancesRespondToSelector:theSelector]) {
    class_addMethod([NSSortDescriptor class],
                    theSelector,
                    (IMP)mySortDescriptorWithKey,
                    "@@:@B");
}
```

Of course, that depends on a C function:

```
id mySortDescriptorWithKeyAscending(id self, SEL _cmd, NSString *key, BOOL ascending) {
    // Put your code here.
}
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I have not tried to compile any of this.

**DISCLAIMER II:** This may be frowned upon by Apple in terms of App Store submission.

Comment: When I have access to an iOS3 device, I'll try this suggestion, and report back!